# Equality not working as expected with ndarray sub-class

Tags: python, numpy

The following example:

```
import numpy as np

class SimpleArray(np.ndarray):

    __array_priority__ = 10000

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

a = SimpleArray(10)
print (np.int64(10) == a)
print (a == np.int64(10))
```

gives the following output

```
$ python2.7 eq.py
True
False
```

so that in the first case, `SimpleArray.__eq__` is not called (since it should always return `False`). Is this a bug, and if so, can anyone think of a workaround? If this is expected behavior, how do I ensure `SimpleArray.__eq__` gets called in both
cases?

EDIT: just to clarify, this *only* happens with Numpy scalar arrays - with normal arrays, `__eq__` always get called because the `__array_priority__` tells Numpy that it should always execute this `__eq__` even if the object is on the RHS of an equality operation:

```
b = SimpleArray([1,2,3])

print(np.array([1,2,3]) == b)
print(b == np.array([1,2,3]))
```

gives:

```
False
False
```

So it seems that with scalar Numpy 'arrays', `__array_priority__` does not get respected.

Comment: AFAIK that's exactly why arithmetic operations have a `__r*__` version, so that subclasses can override it and ensure the correct operation is performed. Unfortunately there is no `__req__` special-method, hence the behaviour you are seeing is expected.

Comment: See edit above - Numpy normally honors the ``__array_priority__`` for arrays, but doesn't seem to do it for 'scalar' arrays.

Comment: This isn't an `__array_priority__` issue, it has to do with the order in which python makes calls to `__op__` vs `__rop__`.

Comment: I do understand, but Numpy does allow the RHS ``__eq__`` to take precedence over the LHS, as I've demonstrated above with arrays - the issue is that Numpy is just reverting to the default Python behavior for Numpy scalars.

Comment: Take a look at my answer bellow, it's not numpy but python that gives RHS __eq__ president in a == b when b is a subclass of a. Notice that your result above will not change if you set the array priority to 0. or -1000.

Comment: I believe Bi Rico is correct. `int64` is not a subclass of `ndarray` hence you shouldn't expect any special behaviour from python or numpy. If you want to have `==` work as you described than you ought to subclass `int64` instead of `ndarray`(and you can probably write some code in `__new__` to convert 1-element arrays into scalars automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhere between a bug and a wart. When you call `a op b` and `b` is a subclass of `a` python checks to see if `b` has a reflected version of `op` and calls that (`__eq__` is the reflected version of itself), So for example this `np.array(10) == a` gives the expected result because SimpleArray is a subclass of ndarray. However because SimpleArray is not an instance of np.int64 it doesn't work in the example you've provided. This might actually be kind of easy to fix on the numpy end of things so you might consider bringing it up on the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

By default, an equality expression `a == b` calls `A.__eq__()` where `A` is the class of variable `a`. This means the type of the left operand dictates which equality function is called. The only way to ensure the equality function you wrote is called, is to ensure your variable is always the left operand. However, in case the left operand has no function for equality, python tries calling `B.__eq__()`

Comment: As I indicated in my edited question, Numpy supports an ``__array_priority__`` attribute which sets whether the LHS or RHS gets called, and it *does* work for arrays, just not Numpy scalars.

Comment: Well, it's called **array** priority for a reason. :P

Answer (score 0):

If `other` is of a different type, operator methods such as `__eq__` need a second reflected function that knows how to handle a comparison in the opposite direction. Since `__eq__` doesn't have a reverse, rather use `__cmp__` and its reverse, `__rcmp__`.

See also http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: `__eq__` is it's own reflected function.

Comment: AFAIK it uses the `__eq__` of whatever class is on the left. Hence true in the sense that you don't ever use a reverse, but false in the sense that some other `__eq__` will be used instead.

Comment: ``__rcmp__`` has been deprecated, so I can't use that. As I indicated in my edited question, Numpy supports an ``__array_priority__`` attribute which sets whether the LHS or RHS gets called, and it does work for arrays, just not Numpy scalars.

Comment: @astrofrog In that case you might want to file a bug report as well as find a workaround. For now just make sure you put the one whose `__eq__` you want Python to use on the LHS. It's bad and you shouldn't have to, but bugs do exist.

Comment: It's not true that "you don't ever use a reverse", for example python calls `b.__eq__(a)` on `a == b` when `a.__eq__(b)` returns NotImplemented or `b` is a subclass of `a`.

Comment: That is a special, not general case; if `a.__eq__(b)` in your example is inappropriate for b then it may return something strange or False because it can't compare.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean this is not general, it is quite general for example `a + b` will call `b.__radd__(a)` if `b` is a subclass of `a` and `a < b` will call `b.__gt__(a)` if `a.__lt__(b)` returns NotImplemented. This is simply following the rules laid out in the "Coercion rules" section of the link you provided above. It just happens that `__eq__` and `__ne__` are their own reflection functions.

Comment: Indeed. My apologies. So in view of this "bug", one should purposefully place the class of which the operator function should be used on the left.